# Serializing query result

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, blob

I have a financial system with all its business logic located in the database and i have to code an automated  workflow for transactions batch processing, which consists of steps listed below:

1. A user or an external system inserts some data in a table
2. Before further processing a snapshot of this data in the form of CSV file with a digital signature has to be made. The CSV snapshot itself and its signature have to be saved in the same input table. Program updates successfully signed rows to make them available for further steps of code
   ...further steps of code

Obvious trouble is step#2: I don't know, how to assign results of a query as a BLOB, that represents a CSV file, to a variable. It seems like some basic stuff, but I couldn't find it. The CSV format was chosen by users, because it is human-readable. Signing itself can be made with a request to external system, so it's not an issue.
Restrictions:

- there is no application server, which could process the data, so i have to do it with plsql
- there is no way to save a local file, everything must be done on the fly

I know that normally one would do all the work on the application layer or with some local files, but unfortunately this is not the case.
Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Surely CSV data would go in a CLOB, not a BLOB? Creating this would consist of manipulating the data with standard text functions such as `||` for concatenation. The database supports CLOB columns, and PL/SQL has CLOB variables. What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @william-robertson.  you just need to create a comma delimited values string (assuming header and data row) and write that to a CLOB.  I recommend an "insert" trigger. There are lots of SQL tricks you can do to make that easier).  On usage of that CSV string will need to be owned by the part of the application that reads it in and needs to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand yo stated you need to create a CVS, but see if you could do XML instead. Then you could use DBMS_XMLGEN to generate the necessary snapshot into a database column directly from the query for it.

I do not accept the concept that a CVS is human-readable (actually try it sometime as straight text). What is valid is that Excel displays it in human-readable form. But is should also be able to display the XML as human-readable. Further, if needed the data in it can be directly back-ported into the original columns.

Just a alternate idea.